# Find k in the following probability density function $F(-2\le x \le 2) = 1$

Tags: probability

[image]

I did

$$\int_{-2}^2 0.25x+kdx = 1 \Leftrightarrow \\
[\frac{x^2}{8}+kx]_{x=-2}^{x=2} =1 \Leftrightarrow \\
(1+2k)-(1-2k)=1\Leftrightarrow \\
4k = 1 \Leftrightarrow k = \frac{1}{4}$$

The solution if $k = \frac{1}{2}$. What went wrong?

Comment: Why would this integral be equal to $1$? You are given the cumulative density not the probability density. You should instead use$$\lim_{x\to2^-}F(x)=0.5+k=F(2)=1$$

Comment: @PeterForeman I guess I got it mixed up with the probability mass function. Thanks. Should it be $F(2) = 1 \Leftrightarrow 0.5 + k = 1 \Leftrightarrow k = .5$ ?

Answer (score 2):

As commented: you are dealing with a CDF $F$ here and we can make use of the fact that $0\leq F(x)\leq1$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$.

- $0\leq F(-2)=-0.5+k$ so that $k\geq0.5$.
- For every $x\in[-2,2)$ we have $0.25x+k=F(x)\leq1$ so that $0.5+k=\lim_{x\to2-}0.25x+k\leq 1$ or equivalently $k\leq0.5$.

This together justifies the conclusion that $k=0.5$.